# Regex exact match

Tags: python, pandas, regex, pattern-matching, extract

I have the following sentence:
"The size of the lunch box is around 1.5l or 1500ml"

How can I change this to:
"The size of the lunch box is around 1.5 liter or 1500 milliliter"

In some cases, the value might also be present as "1.5 l or 1500 ml" with a space.

I am not be able to capture the "l" or "ml" when I am trying to build a function, or it is giving me an escape error.

I tried:

```
def stnd(text):

text = re.sub('^l%',' liter', text) 
text = re.sub('^ml%',' milliliter', text) 

text = re.sub('^\d+\.\d+\s*l$','^\d+\.\d+\s*liter$', text) 
text = re.sub('^^\d+\.\d+\s*ml$%','^\d+\.\d+\s*milliliter$', text) 

return text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a dict to list all the units as the key, and use a pattern to find a digit followed by either `ml` or `l` which you could then use as the key for the dict to get the value.

```
(?<=\d)m?l\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\d)` Positive lookbehind, assert a digit to the left
- `m?l\b` Match an optional `m` followed by b and a word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fTFlIE/1).

Example

```
s = "The size of the lunch box is around 1.5l or 1500ml"
pattern = r"(?<=\d)m?l\b"
dct = {
    "ml": "milliliter",
    "l": "liter"
}
result = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: " " + dct[x.group()] if x.group() in dct else x, s)
print(result)
```

Output

```
The size of the lunch box is around 1.5 liter or 1500 milliliter
```

Comment: I truly think our brains are wired in a similar way `:-)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If that was the case, I would be a SQL guru now..which I am definitely not :-)

Answer (score 3):

We can handle this replacement using a dictionary of lookup values and replacements.

```
d = {"l": "liter", "ml": "milliliter"}
inp = "The size of the lunch box is around 1.5l or 1500ml"
output = re.sub(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(ml|l)', lambda m: m.group(1) + " " + d[m.group(2)], inp)
print(output)

# The size of the lunch box is around 1.5 liter or 1500 milliliter

def stnd(text):
    return re.sub(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(m?l)', lambda m: m.group(1) + " " + d[m.group(2)], text)
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I able to add this to the exact function that I had written in the example? Starting with def stnd(text):. And I am using a column called "description". The input needs to be from a column. At the end I want "return text"

Comment: Last follow-up question. If I need to change "cubic ft." to cubic feet / "kg" to kilogram / oz to ounce; do I only need to make changes in the "(m?l)"

Comment: The regex pattern needs to change to also look for e.g. `ft.`.  Then, you need to add `ft.` to the dictionary along with `feet` as the value replacement.

Comment: Btw in the output you can see (ml|l), but you've returned it as (m?l). Is that correct?

Comment: BTW...why are you changing your question after others have already answered it?

Comment: ? this was a question about your answer.. I saw that you wrote output = re.sub(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(m|l) - I used this formula and then when I checked the answer back, it was changed to output from from (m|l) to (ml|l)

Comment: The question isn't changed?